# How AWS charge for EC2 and S3 Syncs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

If I run aws sync method to sync S3 and EC2 for deploy every minutes, it costs more money? I should run every 5 minutes or so?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about data transfer charges from (and to) S3, there is no charge for data transfer if that happens within the same region. For ex: if your S2 is in Sydney and the EC2 also in Sydney there will be no charge for data transfer. But any data transfer between regions will be charged as "internet data transfer" on BOTH sides.

[See more about S3 Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)

Other than that you will be charged for the number of requests, as sync list and download objects.

[See more about AWS Sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)

Comment: ...and Amazon EC2 is charged per second/per hour, with no additional costs for what you do on the instance (such as running `aws s3 sync`).